# Is there any issue with below code?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a Windows application which reads XML file from given server. This application has installed in about 30 clients. Maybe they will call this function at the same time.

My question:

Will any problem occur if several user call this method at same time?

```
public string GetXmlInnerText()
{  
    FtpWebRequest tmpReq = null;
    System.Net.WebResponse tmpRes = null;
    try
    {
        if (Settings.Default.Internal)
            tmpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://<IPhere>/XMLData.xml");
        else
            tmpReq = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://<IPhere>/XMLData.xml");

        tmpReq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
        tmpReq.KeepAlive = false;
        tmpRes = tmpReq.GetResponse();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //------
    }


    string fileContents = null;
    using (System.IO.Stream tmpStream = tmpRes.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (System.IO.TextReader tmpReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(tmpStream))
        {
            fileContents = tmpReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return fileContents;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem - you're not disposing of the `WebResponse`. It implements `IDisposable`, so you should use a `using` statement. With your current structuring, that's not terribly easy to do - you should consider restructuring your try/catch blocks appropriately.

Further, `StreamReader` uses UTF-8 by default - if your XML documents aren't encoded in UTF-8, you could have problems. If it's an XML document, why not load it via `XmlReader.Create(Stream)` or something similar? That will handle the encoding for you.

Comment: Just wondering why you suggest to restructure instead of simply adding a finally block?

Comment: i have forgot to Dispose WebResponse. Thanks. But with XML Document i have no any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a problem as you are only reading from a file. The only problem could be the server prohibiting concurrent access to a user account and restricts how many connections are allowed at the same time. In that case, you might be better of with a webservice or script (eg. php) delivering the xml via HTTP, not FTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering about multiple clients accessing the FTP server at once, it will depend on how the FTP server is set up.

Some will be set up to only allow 2 or 3 clients at once, whereas some will allow (almost) as many as you could ever need.

If the FTP server causes troubles, you could serve it through a HTTP server instead.